# parseInt() string hash returns integer

Tags: javascript, string, parsing

I have a hash as an ID that I accidentally used parseInt() on.

I am wondering why it returns an actual integer (7) instead of `NaN`

```js
const hash = "7bb94588-4f62-4c41-a782-e5164844cc0d";
console.log(hash);
console.log(typeof hash);
console.log(parseInt(hash))
```

Not really a question in need of help... but I would like to have a better understanding of how JS works.

Comment: You didn't pass a radix so base `10` is assumed. The first char is `7`, so `parseInt` knows the largest digit (base 10) is `7`. The next character is `b`. This doesn't make sense in base 10, so it gives up here and returns the `7`. http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.2.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point.

Comment: Okay, so if the string started with an ‘c’, it would then return NaN?

Comment: Exactly. Unless the radix is 16; then it keeps parsing.

Answer (score 2):

parseInt starts looking at characters from the beginning of the string and when it encounters non-numeric character, cuts away the rest of the string from this position.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt